# Identifying a cluster of polygons based on attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, polygon, geoprocessing, dissolve

I'm trying to identify a cluster of contiguous parcels that, when combined, add up to at least a given size and, when combined, have an assessed property value less than a given $ amount. I have a parcel shapefile with size and value attributes.

Is there a tool that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

The tool which should help you to accomplish this is [Polygon Neighbors (Analysis)](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//000800000045000000):

> Creates a table with statistics based on polygon contiguity (overlaps,
>   coincident edges, or nodes).

Once you know a polygon's neighbors you can work on whether adding attribute values from one or more of them to those of the original polygon will meet your criteria.

To do this I would use ArcPy cursors.

Answer (score -1):

I doubt there is anything simple you can do. I am sure you could come up with something iteratively adding the adjacent polygons with some logic using the required area and the area of the individual adjacent polygons. If you wanted to get fancier and have the script make better decisions you could also incorporate the length of the shared border.

I just watched this video the other day where someone was doing something very similar so I figured I'd point you at it. I know they hate links without answers in the post itself, but hopefully they leave this here long enough for you top see it at least.

https://youtu.be/FDJ3-j0hHnM (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FDJ3-j0hHnM&feature=youtu.be)

The code is posted here:
https://github.com/cfh294/NJMunicipalMergerProject